# Problem while resizing a form - c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that contains (among other things) a chat option.
I have 2 richtextboxes and a button for sending the messages.

[image: The form]

I want that when I resize the form, the messages box will get bigger (or smaller) and that the input box and the button will move down (or up), so they will stay under the messages box.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
    private void MainForm_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle screenRectangle = RectangleToScreen(ClientRectangle);

        int titleHeight = screenRectangle.Top - Top;

        int chatCurrentHeight = richTextBox2.Height;
        int chatNewHeight=Height-titleHeight - richTextBox1.Height - button1.Height - 100;
        richTextBox2.Height = chatNewHeight;
        int heightDiffernce = chatNewHeight - chatCurrentHeight;

        richTextBox1.Location = new Point(richTextBox1.Location.X, richTextBox1.Location.Y+heightDiffernce);
        button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X, button1.Location.Y+heightDiffernce);
    }
```

***richtextbox1 is the input box, and richtextbox2 is the messages box.

It works, but it breaks when the window gets very small (after the size of the messages box is almost 0) and when I minimize the window: The input box and the button disappear.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have a look at [Form.MinimumSize Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.minimumsize?view=netframework-4.8). This should help that the windows does not get too small.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen The problem occurs also when I minimize the window, so it doesn't solve all of the problem

Comment: A TableLayoutPanel with a combination of fixed/proportional cells will help with this layout. Also, as already suggested, set the Form's MinimumSize to at least the size of the panel on the left. The TLP has a MinimumSize property, too.

Comment: The SizeChanged event handler cannot work correctly when the window is minimized.  It needs a check on the WindowState property, just do nothing.

Comment: You should use a [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview); it'll make life so much easier...

Comment: @Idle_Mind is there a way to take the existing controls and put them in a tablelayoutpanel?

Comment: Make your form temporarily big, and then put the TableLayoutPanel off to the side (make sure Dock isn't set to Fill).  Then set it up and **drag and drop** your existing controls into it.  Do not cut and paste add this removes existing event handlers that you'll have to reattach.   When done, set the Dock to Fill on the panel and resize the form.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Idle_Mind.
Use a tablelayoutpanel.

I would use two table layout panels.
1. your main container
2. one for your messages and input

Then, use the 'percent' property of the table layout panel on the row which contains your 'messages' control.

Perhaps, 80% for your messages, 20%, for your input.
Then, dock both richtextboxes so they stretch grow and shrink.